# Is it possible to include a PDF in an HTML SVG element?

Tags: html, svg

I have a PDF file that I would like to put within an HTML SVG element. Does anyone know if this is possible? I've been through [several](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) [other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG) [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and done as many different Google searches as I can think of without any luck.

The closest I've come is a sample which embeds an image at http://svg-wow.org/filterEffects/twirl.svg. If I try do do that with a PDF only the first page will display.

Comment: Well, do you really need to do that? :-) I mean, where the PDF comes from? Can't you convert it beforehand to PNG (if no zoom needed) or SVG? How practical is it to put large PDF documents inside a SVG image? Etc. Sometime, forcing a square peg into a round hole isn't the solution... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). Maybe not exactly what your are looking for (no svg) -  but pretty close.

Comment: We have and unfortunately found it to be extremely slow with large PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

I had to embed a PDF in a SVG years ago. The best solution I could find at that time was to convert the PDF to an SVG and then embed that SVG. I used `pdf2svg` for the conversion and saved the SVG for use in later operations. https://github.com/dawbarton/pdf2svg  (The `pdftocairo` tool may be a better-maintained alternative to `pdf2svg`.)

One issue I encountered and did not solve was that some PDFs convert to very large SVGs.